# Shopware 5 accessing controller variables (Template Variables) on frontend

Tags: shopware

The technical term given in many articles for this is `Template Variables`. I am trying to understand how we can find the variable name given in the controller for a specific field of Shopware 5 front end (ex. Product Name)

For example, I can see the template variable for article name has been given as `$sArticle.articleName`.  I found this when I checked the source code manually.

Let’s say I want to find the discount value given for particular product, How can I print this on my theme? What variable I should use and what is the easy way to find it.

I can assign values from back end for all the variables but my question is how I can access them on my theme file when I update my theme when it comes to technical development side.

Please Note: I am trying to understand the shopware5 technical side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use your variables inside the template you have to write a plugin and assign your controller-variables to the view.

Check out [Globale Variablen im Template verwenden](http://community.shopware.com/Globale-Variablen-im-Template-verwenden_detail_938.html) in the shopware documentation.

If you want to use see which variables are allready assigned, you can use `{debug}` in the template. Also `{$sArticle|var_dump}` is really helpful, if you want to debug a specific variable (`$sArticle}` in this example).

You have to known that shopware assigns the members of an object to the view.

Comment: Thanks, This is use full and I found more details about debugging from this article https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/debugging/. Also, could you please let me know how to find the relevant controller for those variables and what is the approach I should use, in order to add new variable from controller and pass it to the view?

Answer (score 3):

Using the {debug} function will usually give you a list of all assigned variables. This list should also include a variable `$Controller` which will give you a hint to the currently related Controller.

Unfortunately you are not able to identify where the assigned variables come from. Due to the event driven architecture of Shopware the variables can be assigned to the view after the request has been dispatched to the related Controller. This means that variables might he assigned through third party plugins as well as specific event listeners and store front decorators (in Shopware 5).

Kind regards!